# Dipole Moment of the following organic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, dipole

[image: The Question]

Question: Which of the following compounds will show highest dipole moment and why?

I figured out that, (4)th compound is very symmetric - so net dipole moment on the compound must be null.

How should I go about finding the compound with the highest dipole moment? Any help or tips are welcome!

[Question borrowed from the JEE - Main]

Comment: “The image and the title are very self-explanatory.” – Please don’t write such things. Write your question in the [Body box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gkAVe.png). Your question should be clear even without the title. Especially, do not write your whole question in the title and then put something like “title says it all” in the body. Write your question out in full; do not post a picture of the question.

Comment: It is all about aromaticity.

Comment: @IvanNeretin well.. none of the compounds are aromatic out-of-the-box. Perhaps you're hinting that I should alter the compounds a bit and look for aromaticity?

Comment: Well, yeah, sort of.

Comment: @IvanNeretin well.. (IV) is out of the question for highest dipole moment. For aromaticity; one needs conjugation and 4n+2 $\pi$ electrons - this doesn't seem possible for (III). Only options left are (I) and (II). For (II), conjugation could be achieved if I performed some form tautomerism... however condition for 4n+2 electrons fails. Speaking about option (I), thinking of tautomerism doesn't make sense since conjugation of double bonds is impossible as this ring is too small. The least sketchy option is (I) - but I'm not happy with the way I got the answer. How do I make (I) look aromatic?

Comment: By thinking of tautomerism, even if it's making you uncomfortable. Yes, the ring is pretty strained, so what?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm sorry - I didn't understand what you wrote..

Comment: Imagine a form of (I) with a minus on O and plus on the ring.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I get it now. Thanks. That structure you just spoke about is clearly aromatic, and is very stable. So it would be prone to stay like that, hence the big dipole moment it will have, thanks once again.

Comment: Great! You may write an answer yourself, this is allowed and even encouraged.

Comment: @McSuperbX1 if we just switched to looking for orbital I think the carbon atoms attached to the carbonyl at III are sp3 hyperidized so it will the easiest to strip electron cloud off. Right?

Comment: For further studies you may search for quasi-aromaticity.

Comment: Im not sure why this question is closed. What effort could I have possibly shown? I hit a dead end. If Ivan had not given me an idea about aromaticity, I would've remain stuck. This question is from an engineering college entrance examination, intended for 17/18 year olds. It would be helpful if someone could explain how I could've possibly shown more effort. Thank you.